# How to get case profile field option values in supportcase via Netsuite API?

Tags: netsuite

My need is need to create support case via API. At first i can get case fields. Usually we get dropdown options along 
with case fields response. But for Case profile field can't able to get the dropdown options since its the 
dependency field.

**Order of field dependency:**

```
Company -> Subsidiary -> case profile ( We can make sure this in UI )
```

We need to select **Company** dropdown option to get dropdown options for **Subsidiary**, 
also **Case profile** options shows based on **subsidiary** field dropdown options

To get dependency dropdown options we need to create new supportcase record and need to 
set appropriate field values via API. But this is also not work for this case profile field

Any idea how to get case profile dropdown options of support case using netsuite API.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot access the profile records through suitescript. If you go to the Records Browser you will see it is not one of the available records. Another way I check is is to go to the record and enter `nlapiGetRecordType();` into the console, if nothing is returned that a good indication you can't access the record. What is the need to access this record? Maybe there is another way to solve the problem.

Comment: thanks @JonLamb i have added some more information in description.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post has a great trick that often works to get fields values that are not supported directly via scripting. Basically you need to start creating a new record and then look at the field.

http://blog.prolecto.com/2018/07/07/netsuite-suitescript-2-0-lookup-hard-to-search-values/

```
var recordObj = record.create({ type: record.Type.SUPPORT_CASE });
var options = recordObj.getField({ fieldId: 'profile' }).getSelectOptions();
```

Comment: you need to load  the record as dynamic one, {type: record.Type.SUPPORT_CASE, id: '123', isDynamic: true}.